# Why calculate A* Pathfinding F Cost?

Tags: path-finding

I just made an A* Pathfinding system in unity that doesn't calculate the f cost (g cost + h cost) and I wondering why do u actually have to calculate the f cost? I mean my pathfinding system that works perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What cost or distance are you calculating instead?

Comment: The heuristic can be any function that never overestimates the true distance, including the function that is always zero. It sounds like you're choosing to use the function that's always zero, right?

Answer (score 4):

Calculating the F cost allows you to proximate the shortest path and reach your goal faster. Any tile with the lowest F cost should be evaluated first and sorted accordingly, preventing A* from visiting tiles that lead to a worst cost case scenario ( in some cases there is no resolution so that will be the case anyway).

Comment: ... and if your heuristic is always an under (or equal) estimate, you can always find an optimal solution if you need to (so long as you have sound terminal characteristics, and a solution does exist): rarely any reason not to use such a heuristic if available; it is a domain specific concern whether a (faster) heuristic without as strong guarantees is applicable.

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't calculate the f-cost value, then your path finding implementation is probably slow and isn't actually an A* algorithm.

The f-cost is a heuristic estimate for a visited node, that tells you around how long the path is going to be including the exact length of the path to that node and the guessed length of the path from that node to the end. When you choose the next node you'll need to choose the one with the lowest f-cost.

Comment: >and isn't actually an A* algorithm.

Most likely just Dijkstra.

Comment: @Sidar A Dijkstra, a pathfinder based on the heuristic distance to the end node or a breadth first search based on how he chooses the next node. (BFS if he just selects the first)

Comment: Bálint: BFS is for unweighted graphs, Dijkstra's is a generalization of BFS for weighted graphs.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Dijkstra is not a generalization, in fact it's more complex than BFS. Dijkstra picks the node that has the shortest distance from the starter node. BFS always picks from the current level (basically the first element in the array if you store the current nodes like that)

Comment: @Bálint Yeah this is old but I feel I have to clear some things up. Running A* without a heuristic, like OP probably does, makes it run like a Dijkstra search.   [Just check out this gif on the wiki page about Dijkstra](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Dijkstras_progress_animation.gif).

Answer (score 1):

The F cost is an underestimate of the cost from going from the current location to the goal.  It is used to decrease the amount of exploration required to find the right answer.

A* earns its "*" from being "optimal."  What that means is that it accomplishes its goal in the lowest amount of work possible given the information.  It is provable that no algorithm given the same information can do better than A*.  If you have information that can be used to calculate a heuristic underestimate of this cost, and you aren't using it, your algorithm is being inefficient (though it can still work).  On the other hand, if you have more information, then it is possible to write an algorithm that is more efficient than A*.

Comment: _" It is provable that no algorithm given the same information can do better than A\*"_ - Assuming you know _nothing_ more about the constraints of the graph.  If you have, for instance, a 2D grid, you can typically do much better than plain A\*